# How to visit my mother in UK who is in a serious condition at hospital, from India

Tags: visas, uk, emergencies, sri-lankan-citizens

I am a Srilankan national living in India for past 20 years married to a indian girl. i had regular India visa till 2014 and awaiting for 2015 Indian visa yet. My mom and brothers are living in UK, my mom now is in a very serious condition at hospital. i need to visit her immediately as I haven't visited her for past 12 years. please advise in what way I can take a UK visa to visit her.

Comment: Have you tried applying for one?

Comment: This is answered on http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/india/frequently_asked_questions.html . Not sure how can we help beyond that? (And I know link only answers are not encouraged but in this case it's pointless to copy the whole thing)

Comment: Thanks very much for guiding. i have not tried applying one, just gone thro' this link and will apply for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's answered in the Visa office FAQ.

Comment: @chx I don't see where in the help center it says that questions answered elsewhere are off topic.  Besides, if questions could be disqualified by virtue of being answered in the visa office FAQ, 90% of the visa-related questions on this site would have to be closed.

Comment: Then what should be the closing reason , I do not see anything on "this can't be meaningfully answered" -- if it could be surely someone would've stopped commenting and gave an answer.